# SSH Fails at "kex_exchange_identification", "send_error: write: Broken pipe"

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to connect over ssh to an Ubuntu 20.04 on my local Windows.
On running ssh on my local Windows with Putty, it fails to connect.
When checking "service ssh status" command on Ubuntu terminal, it shows message below:

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-07-31 09:40:04 KST; 1h 21min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 8479 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 8482 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38346)
     Memory: 1.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─8482 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
 Server listening on :: port 22.
Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
sshd[8487]: error: kex_exchange_identification: client sent invalid protocol identifier ""
shd[8487]: error: send_error: write: Broken pipe
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've had this happen due to firewall.   Please check logs on both machines and also if there's a company firewall in the mix.